# where on earth is vue-draggable item move to?

Tags: vue.js, vuedraggable

I use **nested** draggable and listen events while drag, then find out that if i drag a itemA into itemB, event throws:

event add => newIndex, element.

event removed => oldIndex, element.

---

It tells me that itemA's index in itemB, but where on earth i konw who is itemB. something I missed?  :3

---

I found it's hard to write a vue-draggable nested-component between 2 pages, i put a simple code to review it in your own computer(not really mine, copy official doc and little change ). code below

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <h3>Nested draggable</h3>
      <nested-draggable :tasks="list" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import nestedDraggable from "./infra/nested";
export default {
  name: "nested-example",
  display: "Nested",
  order: 15,
  components: {
    nestedDraggable
  },
  data() {
    return {
      list: [
        {
          name: "task 1",
          tasks: [
            {
              name: "task 2",
              tasks: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "task 3",
          tasks: [
            {
              name: "task 4",
              tasks: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "task 5",
          tasks: []
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped></style>
```

and infra/nested

```
<template>
  <draggable class="dragArea" tag="ul" :list="tasks" :group="{ name: 'g1' }" @change="changed">
    <li v-for="el in tasks" :key="el.name">
      <p>{{ el.name }}</p>
      <nested-draggable :tasks="el.tasks" />
    </li>
  </draggable>
</template>
<script>
import draggable from "@/vuedraggable";
export default {
  props: {
    tasks: {
      required: true,
      type: Array
    }
  },
  components: {
    draggable
  },
  name: "nested-draggable",
  methods: {
    changed (event) {
      console.log(event)
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.dragArea {
  min-height: 50px;
  outline: 1px dashed;
}
</style>
```

---

So far, pass a el.list can calculate its index with save level element, though, drag in a **empty list** need to be prevented.

Comment: Hi Jay, could you please post a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can get a better understanding of your issue?

Comment: sorry, forgot it. will be soon

Comment: You can emit the event with `list` variable which change event fired. See https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-browser-y4qwf.  You can also make some debounce function to merge those events together. See https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-shadow-fptom. If you want more about parent list you can also pass up for each every recursive.

Comment: thanks, this helps. with same level list on remove and add, could do easier than a list circle, especially when a big list will be time comsuming